# Does CompositeDisposable.dispose() Interrupt Tasks.await() in an Rx Subscription?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, rx-java, rx-java2

Is it normal for `Tasks.await()` from `com.google.android.gms.tasks` to be interrupted when `CompositeDisposable.dispose()` is called in an Rx subscription? I thought Rx operations run to completion by default.

In other words `Tasks.await()` throws `InterruptedException` when the Rx subscription is disposed, I don't understand how and why there are not information about this.

```
addSubscription(Completable.create(emitter -> {
        try {
            //some operation with Tasks.await()
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            if (!emitter.isDisposed()){
                emitter.onError(e);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            if (!emitter.isDisposed()){
                emitter.onError(e);
            }
        }
        
        if (!emitter.isDisposed()){
            emitter.onComplete();
        }
    }).subscribeOn(getIoScheduler()).observeOn(getMainThreadScheduler()).subscribe(() -> {
        //on complete
    },throwable -> {
        throwable.printStackTrace();
    }));
```